# netbeans autocomplete not working depending on chosen variable name

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, namespaces

i'm having this weird autocomplete issue and i'm having troubles finding the cause.

I allready tried removing cache directories, but to no avail!
I've also tried typehinting/phpdocs ( /**@return classname*/ but again, without solving the issue.

sidenote: sorry for the bad crop in first screen :p

the issue:
[image]

however, when i use a different variable name it does work:

[image]

Would you guys consider this being a bug from netbeans? or am i missing something?
I do have to say, my function 'fetchById($id)' does return different types depending application logic.

Comment: is `$file` already defined elsewhere in the same scope? Perhaps in a class that is being extended. I think @Jan is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow underline in your second screenshot makes be believe that the problem might be introduced by multiple variable assignments in the code which is not visible in the screenshot. But that's just a guess.